# one property from my ViewModel will not populate ModelMetadata

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm experiencing very odd behavior in the way an ASP.NET MVC3 view model is emitted -- for one field, ModelMetadata is not propagated. I'm using the templated helpers after [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html), though updated for Razor. Here's my view model:

```
public class FamilyBaseViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [Display(Order = 10)]
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    [Display(Order = 30)]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Street name can only be 50 characters long.")]
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class FamilyPrivateViewModel : FamilyBaseViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Date Started", Order = 20)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DateStarted { get; set; }
}
```

The object.cshtml template runs through the properties and uses Html.Display to show them:

```
// object.cshtml
 <ol>
            @foreach (var prop in
            ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay
                            && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm)
                            && pm.ModelType != typeof(System.Data.EntityState)))
            {
                <li>
                @Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)
                </li>
            }
        </ol>
```

In the above scenario, all three fields have the right descriptors in the object.cshtml call (prop.DisplayName, prop.TemplateHint), but when the first property -- FamilyName -- is passed to String.cshtml, the ViewData.ModelMetadata is not populated at all. As a result, the template can't display a label (except "String"), nor assign the ID of the control, etc.

Street and DateStarted are emitted normally, with the ID and all. So I'm completely at a loss as to why the one property would fail to set the ViewData properties -- nor do I know how to step through past the Html.Display call to see what might be happening.

Any ideas for a next place to look?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the controller action, which for unrelated reasons used "FamilyName" for a ViewData value:

```
     ViewBag.FamilyName = familyName;
```

And this caused all heck to break loose in the mapping of model fields with the same name -- that is, ModelMetadata will not propagate. So, the lesson is: don't give ViewData dictionary items keys with the same name as a field in your view model.